# Программирование java

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Добрый день, объясните пожалуйста как работает этот код и что такое синглетон? я немного понимаю, но преподу нужно точная формулировка каждой строчки

```
public class A(){
    private static A a;
    public static A get_a(){
      if(a == null){
        a = new A;
      }
      return a;
    }
}
```

СПАСИБО!!

Answer (score 4):

Синглетон - это класс для которого возможно создать один-единственный экземпляр.

Код с исправленным синтаксисом.

```
public class A {            // объявляем класс А
    private static A a;      // объявляем статическое поле того же типа, что и класс.
    public static A getA() { // статический метод возвращающий экземпляр класса А
      if(a==null)            //   если поле а не инициализиировано, то
        a=new A;             //   создаем новый экземпляр
      return a;              //   и возвращаем его
    }
}
```

Таким образом, сколько раз мы бы ни вызывали `A.getA()` мы будем получать один и тот же экземпляр класса А, на который ссылается поле `a`.

---

На самом деле это не настоящий синглетон. Мы все еще можем вызвать `new A()` и получить новый экземпляр. Чтобы это исключить, нужно сделать конструктор скрытым.

```
public class A {            
    private static A a;      
    public static A getA() {
      if(a==null)           
        a=new A;            
      return a;             
    }

    private A() {}  // конструктор объявлен как приватный, теперь никто не сможет создать экземпляр напрямую.
}
```

Замечу, что это самая простая, "наивная", реализация синглетона, призванная продемонстрировать его свойства, но как правило не годящаяся для использования в работе.

Чтобы узнать какие проблемы есть у синглетона, и как различные его вариации помогают их решить, почитайте литературу по шаблонам проектирования.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, а исправление синтексиса, это замена `get_A()` на `getA()` и удаление пары лишних скобочек?

@Lana15, к совету почитать литературу, я бы добавил -- обратите там внимание на методы `.wait` и `.notify`, а также на многопоточность (тогда станет понятней, "откуда ногои растут" и что именно имел в виду @Nofate ♦, говоря о "наивной" реализации).

Comment: @avp, пост сейчас уже пофикшен ) Изначально не хватало пары фигурных скобок, точек с запятой и были лишние пробелы.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, тогда извиняюсь. Сейча поправлю свой коммент.

Answer (score 3):

> объясните пожалуйста как работает этот код

код, что вы привели, не работает вообще никак - в нем уйма синтаксических ошибок. Рискну предположить, что он должен выглядеть так:

```
class A {
    private static A a;

    public static A getA() {
          if(a==null)
            a = new A();
          return a;
    }
}
```

Собственно, по теме вопроса. Синглтон - это примерно то, что вы привели в своем коде (с учетом поправок на ошибки). То есть класс, который должен существовать в программе только в одном экземпляре. Иногда такие классы бывают очень полезны. Как это работает? Синглтон написан таким образом, что у пользователя (то есть программиста, который работает с этим кодом) нет прямой возможности создать этот класс. Впрочем, именно в вашем коде такая возможность есть. Чтобы это исправить, нужно его модифицировать так:

```
class A {
    private static A a;

    private Singleton () {} // конструктор должен быть закрытым
    public static A getA() {
          if(a==null)        // {1}
            a = new A();

          return a;
    }
}
```

Так вот, доступ к экземпляру этого класса возможен только через статичный метод getA, который возвращает единственный экземпляр этого класса, если он  существует. А если не существует, то создает и возвращает его (см. строку **{1}** в примере). В общем, все довольно просто. Однако приведенная выше реализация не идеальна, поскольку не учитывает возможность работы  нескольких потоков с вашим синглтоном. На этот случай есть более хитрые реализации этого паттерна. О том, что такое паттерн, а также о других реализациях можете почитать [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8)

Answer (score 2):

А почему до сих пор никто не предложил классический потокобезопасный паттерн?

```
public class А {
    private А() { }

    private static class Creator {
        private static final A INSTANCE = new A();
    }

    public static А getInstance() {
        return Creator.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

(Кто понимает, почему этот способ потокобезопасный (и ленивый), и для чего нужен внутренний класс, поставьте себе плюсик в карму.)

---

Построчное объяснение

```
public class A { // скобки после имени класса не нужны - не скомпилируется
    private static A a; // здесь храним единственный экземпляр класса
                        // private потому что не хотим, чтобы кто-то снаружи мог
                        // поменять, static потому что к нему надо иметь доступ если
                        // под рукой нет экземпляра
    public static A get_a() { // а это метод получения экземпляра
                              // как правильно заметили уже все, методы принято
                              // называть в стиле getA
      if (a == null) { // вначале поле a пустое. при первом вызове мы его заполняем
                       // почему не заранее? на случай, если синглтон
                       // вообще никому не понадобится.
        a = new A;  // собственно, создаём и запоминаем в статическом поле
                    // когда метод get_a будет вызван второй раз, мы сюда уже
                    // не попадём и отдадим экземпляр, созданный в первый раз
      }
      return a; // в этой точке экземпляр гарантированно создан, возвращаем его
    }
    // надо ещё закрыть конструктор от внешнего использования, а то клиент
    // сможет создать экземпляр в обход ваших защитных механизмов
}
```

Comment: @VladD, текст в скобочках -- это опрос участноков (скажем, путем комментирования)?

Comment: @avp: да :) Но если кто знает, плиз не раскрывайте сразу, пусть другие поинтересуются. Просто отпишитесь, кто знает (и кто НЕ знает).

Comment: Отписываюсь, знаю )

Answer (score 1):

Синглтон это класс, колличество экземпляров которого определено. Для этого, конструктор объекта должен быть private. Тогда экземпляр объекта можно будет получить только статическим методом, в данном случае get_a, поскольку private конструктор может вызывать только сам класс в котором он объявлен.

Но в данном примере приватного конструктора нет, есть только статическое поле private static A a, которое иннициализируется при первом вызове get_a. А экземпляров этого класса я могу наделать сколько угодно.

Вот отличный [пример](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternSingleton/article.html). Там первый пример с enum - это современный и правильный для джавы способ, поскольку инстанс enum гарантированно не убьется garbage collector'ом посреди исполнения программы кроме того он serializable изначально, что может оказаться удобно. Второй, классический, в таком виде работает практически на любом ОО языке.

Comment: Синглтоны не обязательно имеют один объект (несмотря на название). Но их должно быть определенное (разработчиком) количество.

Comment: @Free_ze, ну да, можно приделать счетчик экземпляров. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

PS Извините, но это основы основ, лучше многих из нас вам может объяснить хороший учебник по Java.

Comment: @Free_ze, увы, статья на вики чуть более чем ни о чем.

Comment: Куда полезнее эти статьи с хабра:

 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/27108/
 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/129494/
 - http://habrahabr.ru/post/134637/

Комментарии тоже читать.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, вы ее читали? Есть и определение, и примеры на Java.

Comment: @Nofate ♦, считайте, что вы меня убедили, что есть источники лучше) Однако, мой основной посыл был в книжки, а это первое дело, когда просят прокомментировать код построчно.

Comment: Ну да, целых три реализации без объяснения, что это и почему так. И где double locking singleton с объяснением его тонких мест?

Comment: @Nofate ♦, там есть названия, гуглить можно)

Answer (score 0):

Синглтон это написание английского слова singleton кириллицей, которым пользуются невежественные люди, толком не знающие ни русского, ни английского языка. В переводе означает "одиночка".

Означает этот код то, что вызывая getA вы будете всегда получать ссылку на один и тот же объект, который будет создан при первом вызове этой функции.