# Php подключение к mysql в конструкторе класса

Tags: php

```
<?php
    class BS 
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""));
            @mysql_select_db("DataBaseName");
        }
    }
?>
```

Есть класс BS, получается, что при каждом создании объекта типа BS, будет новое соединение с БД?

Если - да, то как этого избежать, кроме того, как убрать его из конструктора?

Comment: @Скрыто1 научитесь уже форматировать код, в который раз пишете эту невнятную кашу.

По сабжу - а зачем вам вообще понадобилось засовывать логику подключения к бд в конструктор?

Comment: @elfinorr не стоит превращать Хэшкод в помойку вроде ответов@Mail.ru  - это там любят всех слать в гугл и называть дебилами

@Скрыто1 выбирайте выражения

Answer (score 1):

Не заморачивайтесь http://php.net/mysql_connect :

> Описание
>
> resource mysql_connect ([ string
> $server =
> ini_get("mysql.default_host") [,
> string $username =
> ini_get("mysql.default_user") [,
> string $password =
> ini_get("mysql.default_password") [,
> bool $new_link = false [, int
> $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )
>
> Открывает новое соединение с сервером
> MySQL или **использует уже существующее**.

Но расширение mysql лучше не использовать, так как оно устарело! Приглядитесь к mysqli или PDO

Ну если вас все-таки не по себе от постоянных вызовов ф-и соединения, создайте статическую переменную для доступа к БД, а затем перед вызовом в конструкторе проверяйте не открыто ли уже соединение. Типа этого:

```
class  BS {
    ...
    public static $link = NULL;
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!self::$link)
            self::$link = mysql_connect(...);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

ЗЫ Ну не удержусь, приведу еще один способ))):

```
$link = mysql_connect(...); // Где-нибудь вне BS, например, в глобальном пространстве или другом классе
...
class  BS {
...
private $link;
public function __construct($link)
{
    if($link)
        $this->link = $link;
    else
        ...; // Какие-то действия по обработке ошибки, например, выброс исключения
    ...
}
...

}
```

Comment: Да по-хорошему все равно нужны выделение подключения в отдельный объект и DI, ибо к 99% объектов сама база данных никакого отношения не имеет, и переход на другой движок будет болезненным.

Answer (score 1):

Не особо знаком с PHP, поэтому не стану говорить о каких-то средствах, присущих конкретно этому языку.

Вообще засовывать логику подключения к базе данных в конструктор - идея так себе. Более того, не вижу причин, почему эта логика обязательно должна быть в конструкторе, а не где-то ещё. В принципе вынести это из конструктора в отдельный метод было бы вполне логично.

Однако если по [каким-то причинам](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82&oq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8677j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) вы все же решили создавать подключение к базе непременно из конструктора, то вам имеет смысл узнать/вспомнить  про такой паттерн проектирования, как синглтон. В принципе он как раз нужен для подобных случаев - он позволяет создавать единственный экземпляр данного класса для последующей с ним работы. Существует ряд различных реализаций этого паттерна, самая простая из котрых (и не очень правильная, посмкольку не учитывает аспекты многопоточности) подразумевает закрытый конструктор и статическое свойство, по которому происходит обращение к приватной переменой-экземпляру этого класса. Недавно здесь же этот паттерн обсуждался [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301512/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-java), советую ознакомиться